# Id is found Null in case of Edit and Delete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I am creating an invoice table in ASP.NET Core and using jquery. And Id is found Null while editing or deleting invoice.

I am trying to edit invoice details by Id But it founds Null.

```
public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    var existingInvoice = _context.Invoices
                                  .Include(i => i.LineItems)
                                  .Include(i => i.Customer)
                                  .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);

    if (existingInvoice == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var viewModel = new CreateInvoiceViewModel
    {
        Invoice = existingInvoice,
        InvoiceId = existingInvoice.Id,
        InvoiceNumber = existingInvoice.InvoiceNo,
        InvoiceDate = existingInvoice.InvoiceDate,
        CustomerName = existingInvoice.Customer.FirstName,
        CustomerAddress = existingInvoice.Customer.Address,
        DueDate = existingInvoice.DueDate,
        LineItems = existingInvoice.LineItems.ToList()
    };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingInvoice.FilePath))
    {
        viewModel.FilePath = existingInvoice.FilePath;
    }
    
    CalculateTotalAmount(viewModel);
    PopulateDropdowns();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Script like....

```
return `<div class="text-center">
               <a href="/Invoice/Edit/${data.Id}" class="block rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-2 text-center text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600">
               Edit
           </a>
              <button class="block rounded-md bg-red-600 px-3 py-2 text-center text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
                onclick="Delete('/Invoice/Delete/${data.Id}')">
               Delete
              </button>
       </div>`;
```

Comment: Could you please share how you build your html and not only the Script like....return... ?

Comment: Sure..But I don't know how to share it here

Comment: Please just put it in your post, like you did with other pieces of code.

Comment: That means you doesn't really get the `data.Id` value. I cannot see how did you get this value. please post more related code. Besides, is there any routing attributes on top of the edit method?